# jekyll: check if there are no posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I check if there are no posts in the `_posts` folder?

So far, I've tried

```
{% if site.posts == null %}
  <p>No posts...yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if site.posts == nil %}
  <p>No posts...yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible in Liquid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab the size of the posts array and then compare that to 0:

```
{% assign psize = site.posts | size %}
{% if psize == 0 %} 
  <p>No posts...yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either (i.e. this doesn't show the `<p>` element).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler approach.

```
{% if site.posts.size == 0 %}
  <p>No posts...yet.</p>
{% endif %}
```