# Liquid/Jekyll: How to check for no posts when one has two or more conditions?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am having trouble understanding how I might show a "no posts exist" message for a particular conditional statement with two variables.

In this example, let's say I have a collection of "animals" - on a particular page, I'd like a section that displays "primates that are herbivores":

```
  {% for animal in site.animal %}
    {% if animal.species == "primate" and animal.type == "herbivore" %}

      {{ animal.content }}

    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

What I'd like to do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
{% if POSTS_EXIST_FOR_THIS_COMBO: (animal.species == "primate" and animal.type == "herbivore") %}
      {% for animal in site.animal %}
        {% if animal.species == "primate" and animal.type == "herbivore" %}
          {{ animal.content }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
{% else %}
     There are no posts for this category.
{% endif %}
```

Note: This differs from examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208588/jekyll-check-if-there-are-no-posts), because I have two parameters to check. Can someone offer a suggestion about the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do the following where you at first filter all by `species=primate` from `site.animal` and then filter by `type=herbivore` from that pool and then check if the result exists.

```
{% assign animals = site.animal | where:"species","primate" | where:"type","herbivore" %}

{% if animals %}
  {% for animal in animals %}
    {{ animal.content }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps.